# Limit POST requests for a certain page

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can I disallow POST requests on a certain page of the website?

Like disallow POST on http://site.com

but allow it on subpages, like `http://site.com/whatever` or `http://site.com/post.php`

---

The problem is an old script that was handling such requests.
This script is now inactive, however such requests still come, and burden the server.
I want to somehow block them

Answer (score 4):

It is not recommended to use the `<Limit>` directive for access control in most cases, but in your situation this may be your best option:

```
<VirtualHost>
  ServerName example.net
  ...

  <Location /post.php>
    <Limit POST>
      Order deny,allow
      Deny from all
    </Limit>
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

The code above will return `403 Forbidden` for POST requests for http://example.net/post.php. 
More information about the [Limit directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limit).